# Typewriter text effect usability

Tags: usability, readability, typography

I've been asked to implement, and have seen this typewriter effect on a number of web sites: https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Typically it is in the header with 3 or 4 sentences about what the company or service does. I'm not sold on the idea, while it might be a "cool" effect, will users hang about waiting for the sentences to load or skim and scroll past it? Or am I just being a kill joy?

Just looking for some expert opinions on this technique and if it is an OK or bad experience.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience and also from the opinion of a great ui/ux designer that I followed recently, it is a bad experience in most cases.

- First, you have to wait for the sentence to complete. The more sentence you have, the longer time the user wastes
- Second, for someone who has a problem with reading text, they almost can't read your sentence at all or have to wait until the sentence is typed again. That is really annoying
- Finally, user usually can't promptly get the idea of what your website can help them, so likely close the website right away

Of course, it is a nice effect. But if you want to implement that, make sure to use a few keywords and combine it with another way to show your website features instead of depending on it alone

Answer (score 0):

The method can’t be judged in isolation, it all depends on the context.

Your example previews the use of a command line tool so it’s purposeful and not at all gratuitous. Speaking as someone who enjoys software development and wants to get better at it I feel your example provides [affective priming](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/priming/) consistent conducive to the subject matter.